# Crystal reports 13 - barcode doesn't show in viewer

Tags: barcode, crystal-reports-2010

I have a weird situation: in design and preview  my report showing barcode properly but in report viewer or exported in PDF report's behaviour is like I dont have a referenced font (Free 3 of 9).
Is there any cure for such things?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I've got the exact same issue. I can export and print it perfectly fine, but in the viewer (asp.net served page) I see * BarcodeText *

Answer (score 0):

Check if the font is embeddable in PDFs. Got to the fonts-folder in windows, right click the font and check the properties. There should be some entry saying that embedding is allowed.

Edit:
Here is my (german) propery-dialog of font:
[image: font properties in german windows]

Comment: plz see my edit and the screenshot. it's german but its telling you the embedability (not installability!) of a font.

Comment: :-)! But thats exactly the information, I DON'T need. I want to know if it is embedable. Installable is clear so far.